# when( expression ){ do stuff }

Tags: programming-languages

Does anybody know in which programming language can you use this:

```
when( expression ){ do stuff }
```

It is supposed to register the expression and the code block in some array which in turn is parsed every Q mili-/micro-/nanoseconds by a background thread and, for every expression that evaluates to true, execute it's respective code block.

As you might think, I already have an implementation. I'm asking because I think it would be nice to have it supported natively in some programming languages.

For whom might ask what is the use for such an instruction- imagine that you create some variables/ objects in your program an want to have a procedure executed every time / while / whenever the variable/object has a certain value/state. The advantage is that you wouldn't have to bind the code to the variable/object and more they even wouldn't have to exist at the time you declare the `when(){}`.
It would be some sort of a trigger

Comment: Sounds interesting, but not something I'd heard of implemented natively in a language. The closest thing would probably be an event? But even that is dependant on the application, not so much the language implementation. It would also rely on the initial author, rather than the end code writer.

Comment: It looks like a Broadcast Receiver in Android (but with different syntactic sugar).

Comment: It would go against the principle of encapsulation if these were implemented on a global scale which I think you're implying.

Comment: Turbo Basic from 1987 (and probably other BASIC implementations from that era) had some event handlers of the form `ON event GOSUB label` that you would declare generally at the top of the file and they would call your labelled subroutine whenever the event occured. It had `ON COM(n)` for serial port events, `ON KEY(n)` for hotkeys, `ON PEN` for light-pen (whatever that was) event handling, `ON PLAY` for letting you know when the music note buffer was empty, `ON STRIG` for the joystick, and `ON TIMER(seconds)` for anything else you needed. It would check them between every statement.

Comment: Thank you guys for answering. I must say, I didn't expect so many ( and such clear ) answers.

Comment: Message handline and passing is a basic feature of many languages, smalltalk being the canonical example, but also erlang and any object oriented language.  `when(...) do {...}` is what happens when you have a method on a class in basically all OOP languages.

Comment: The syntax is identical to the one used by [Perl’s switch statement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) (a.k.a. `given`).

Comment: I am afraid I wasn't clear enough;

Answer (score 0):

The SR language has a construct very similar to the one you look for. 
There the syntax is

```
do guard -> command 
[] guard -> command
[] guard -> command
...
od
```

You can find information (and implementation) here: http://www.cs.arizona.edu/sr/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any language level constructs like what you describe but it sounds similar in principle to what [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/intro.html) does with its observables. I believe that the Observable type is due to be incorporated into future versions of Javascript as well.

It looks a little different:

```
observable.doNext(() => { // do stuff })
```

vs:

```
when(expression) { // do stuff }
```

In the example you give your expression would return something akin to a ReactiveX observable, and the body of the statement could be equated to `.doNext(() => do stuff)`. In fact Rx provides a number of options for how to handle different observable events and it can do some really powerful stuff allowing you to chain operations.

Answer (score 0):

The [Software Transactional Memory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.4.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-STM.html) library for Haskell has something similar:

```
do
    a <- readTVar x
    b <- readTVar y
    check (a < b)
    writeTVar z (b - a)
```

This will read the current values of `x` and `y` into `a` and `b`, and wait until `a < b` becomes true before it continues to the next line.

It does so *without busy-waiting*. If the condition `a < b` is false, it aborts the transaction and starts listening for writes to the TVars that were read so far, namely `x` and `y`. When it's notified that one of the TVars were updated, only then does it restart the transaction from the top to attempt it again.